# How can I correct include path for webjars?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, webjars

I'm trying to include Bootstrap 4 within my Spring Boot project, but I'm seeing the error: `Bootstrap tooltips require Popper.js`

So I included the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
  <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    <version>0.32-1</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I include it inside the page I can' find the the popper.js . Why?

This is what I used:

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/npm/popper.js/popper.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What is the correct path to include it?

EDIT:

Same problem with font-awesome:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/dist/font-awesome.min.css}" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I loaded that library into my workspace, it indicates this path: `META-INF/resources/webjars/popper.js/1.13.0/dist`. So try it:

1. without `/npm` in path
2. with version number
3. with `dist` folder

   ```
   <script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/1.13.0/dist/popper.min.js}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

**EDIT: (Reaction on comment)**

Font awesome JAR has a lot of different folders in WebJAR distribution. Look at my IJ screenshot:

[image]

So for highlighted file in screenshot, you would use

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/5.0.2/svg-with-js/css/fa-svg-with-js.css}" />
```

Hope that after whowing the screenshot you understand how these webjar folders work. WebJAR just adds bunch of UI resources to your WEB-INF/resources folder and you need to figure out correct path from your workspace.

Comment: Yeah,. Adding `dist`  folder was 3rd change I suggested.

Comment: Yes yes, I saw it... But if add dist to include fornt-awesome it doesn't work... Why?

Comment: For fon't awesome, I suggest to do same thing I did, load the webjar dependency to your workspace and inspect the path of that dependency.

Comment: Font awesome wasn't part of this question. Can you update it which artifact you use?

Answer (score 0):

In case of eclipse / sts i added dependency like following in pom.xml

```
    <!-- bootstrap and jquery -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
         <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
         <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then in html template i added url by going through maven dependency file structure inside

popper.js-2.0.2.jar->META-INF->resources->webjars->popper.js->2.0.2->umd->popper.js

so path i have added as following

```
<script src="webjars/popper.js/2.0.2/umd/popper.js"></script>
```

similarly we can add proper path for webjar dependency following is screenshot [image: screenshot] for reference